# What are the hours in which Apple reviews apps?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

What are the hours in which Apple reviews apps? I.e., 7:00 AM - 9:00 PM

Comment: At their own convenience would be my best guess...

Comment: @SolarMike I just wanted to know if there was a specific in and out for the app review time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no fixed hours for Apple's app review process. Besides notice given for closure over holiday periods (shown if relevant in iTC), Apple does not talk about the times it reviews apps.